# computed column specification to convert ISO8601 date with timezone Z to SQL datetime

Tags: sql-server-2012, calculated-columns, isodate

`convert(datetime,'2015-03-06T23:59:04Z',127)` yields a MS-SQL datetime:

2015-03-06 23:59:04.000

If we have an actual column called [isodate] defined either as varchar(20) or char(20), is it possible to use that conversion as the formula of a **Computed Column Specification** in SQL Server 2012?

I am getting "error validating the formula" with eithe of these formulas:

`(convert([datetime],[isodate],127))`
`(convert(datetime,[isodate],127))`

Comment: remove the brackets around [datetime], shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just have a syntax error. Removing the brackets from `[datetime]` in your formula should do the trick.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null drop table #temp

create table #temp (isodate varchar(20))

insert into #temp (isodate) values
('2015-03-06T23:59:04Z'),
('2016-03-04T13:59:04Z')

select isodate, convert(datetime,[isodate],127) as DT from #temp

--select convert(datetime,'2015-03-06T23:59:04Z',127)
```

Comment: I wish it were that simple.  The formula is still being rejected as a valid Computed Column Specification formula, after the brackets are removed.

Comment: seems like a trivial question, but are you sure all of the values in [isodate] can be converted? i.e. there isn't any corrupted data? And just to be sure, [isodate] itself isn't a computed column (at any stage of it's existence) is it? I just noticed the extra parentheses so assume this is nested inside of other statements.

Comment: Ah, it's always something small!